# Is it possible to obtain number of 404 responses from apache exporter?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am trying to create a dashboard on Grafana for the number of 404 responses for an apache server and have apache exporter installed. on the metrics page i can see the total number of 200 response codes

```
# HELP http_requests_total Total number of HTTP requests made.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{code="200",handler="prometheus",method="get"} 129084
```

Is it possible to configure the same for 404 codes ? and if so where can it be done ?

Comment: which specific exporter do you use?

Comment: it was already setup before i started working on it but i believe it was this one Lusitaniae/apache_exporter